# How to sort a list of stings by number letter first and then number

Tags: java, collections

I have a string list as follows:

```
(2D, 1D, 1Y, 23M, 4M, 2Y, 12D)
```

How can I sort it alphabetically and then numerically?

I expect

```
(1D, 2D, 12D, 4M, 23M, 1Y, 2Y)
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator());

public class MyComparator implements Comparator {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        String s1 = (String)o1;
        String s2 = (String)o2;
        String strPart1 = s1.split("")[1];
        int intPart1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.split("")[0]);

        String strPart2 = s2.split("")[1];
        int intPart2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.split("")[0]);

        int strCompareResult = strPart1.compareTo(strPart2);
        if(0 == strCompareResult )
        {
            return intPart1 - intPart2;
        }
        else
        {
            return strCompareResult;
        }
    }

}
```

However this did not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this did not work"?

Comment: Is there always exactly one letter at the end?

Comment: yes there is always 1 letter a the end.

Comment: Your code assumes every string is exactly 2 characters long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort first by the last character, then parse the other characters as an `int`. The `Comparator` can be written more easily with the `Comparator.comparing` and `.thenComparing` methods.

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.charAt(s.length() - 1))
    .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to code more defensively and make it work for letters and numbers of arbitrary length:

```
        List<String> sorted = strings.stream().
            sorted(Comparator.comparing((String s) ->s.replaceAll("\\d", "")).
                    thenComparingInt(s ->Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("\\D", "")))).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(sorted);
```

Comment: You may want to note that this only works for arbitrary lengths of digits `> 0`. Otherwise, a String like `"MMM"` will be parsed as `""` and result in a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that splits the string between the last digit and the character using a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

This defines a comparator to use the split string to first compare the `String` portion and then, if the strings are equal, compares the `int` portion after parsing.

```
List<String> stringList = List.of(
        "2D","1D","1Y","23M","4M","2Y","12D"
);

Comparator<String> comp = Comparator
.comparing(str -> str.split("(?=\\D)"),
        Comparator.comparing((String[] str) -> str[1])
                .thenComparingInt(str->Integer.parseInt(str[0])));
   
   
List<String> list = stringList.stream().sorted(comp).toList();

System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[1D, 2D, 12D, 4M, 23M, 1Y, 2Y]
```

If you want to expand this to handle any number of trailing characters > 0 you could replace the above split invocation with the following:

```
str.split("((?<=\\d)(?=\\D))|((?=\\d)(?!\\d))")
```

In all cases, at least one character and one digit is required, else an exception could be thrown.